# Typescript Interface specification with hash

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this interface where I basically want to have an array of hashes. Something like this (propably not correct):

```
export interface EntitySpec {
  originId: EntityType;
  mandatoryProperties: Array<{ [key: string]: string }>;
}
```

But I want to apply the interface like this:

```
const spec: EntitySpec = {
  originId: 1,
  mandatoryProperties: {
    'code': 'sad',
    'name': 'this',
    'comment': 'here',
  },
};
```

But I get this: Type '{ code: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }[]'.
How would I do this properly?

Comment: You've defined "mandatoryProperties" to be an array, yet you aren't passing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `mandatoryProperties` is an `Array` of objects. Wrap that into `[]` and you should be fine:

```js
const spec: EntitySpec = {
  originId: 1,
  mandatoryProperties: [
    {
      'code': 'sad',
      'name': 'this',
      'comment': 'here',
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. A little thing which makes a great difference :-)

Comment: @Jonas if this answer solved your problem would you accept it as the correct answer?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to assign an `object` to `mandatoryProperties`, remove `Array<>` from an interface as follows:

```
export interface EntitySpec {
  originId: EntityType;
  mandatoryProperties: { [key: string]: string };
}

const spec: EntitySpec = {
  originId: 1,
  mandatoryProperties: {
    'code': 'sad',
    'name': 'this',
    'comment': 'here',
  },
};
```

else wrap the `mandatoryProperties` inside an array as follows:

```
export interface EntitySpec {
  originId: EntityType;
  mandatoryProperties: Array<{ [key: string]: string }>;
}

const spec: EntitySpec = {
  originId: 1,
  mandatoryProperties: [{
    'code': 'sad',
    'name': 'this',
    'comment': 'here',
  }],
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Your `mandatoryProperties` is an object, not an array. You need to remove that `Array<>`

```
export interface EntitySpec {
  originId: EntityType;
  mandatoryProperties: { [key: string]: string };
}
```

However, if you need an array,then you can add `[]` at the end:

```
export interface EntitySpec {
  originId: EntityType;
  mandatoryProperties: { [key: string]: string }[];
}

const spec: EntitySpec = {
  originId: 1,
  mandatoryProperties: [
    {
      'code': 'sad',
      'name': 'this',
      'comment': 'here',
    }
  ]
};
```